# Problems with permalinks after update wordpress 4.2

Tags: permalinks

Yesterday i will update my wordpress to 4.2 and after update it i see some link of my blog end with `%d`

And Some post in my blog show like `%d8%b9%d8%a8%d8%af%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%b1%d8%ad%d9%85%d9%86-%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%b9%d8%ac%d8%a7%d8%ac%d9%8a-%d9%8a%d9%82%d8%b7%d8%b9-%d9%85%d8%a7%d8%b1%d8%a7%d8%ab%d9%88%d9%86-%d9%85%d8%a7%d9%86%d8%b4%d8%/`.

Before update all link work good, and o restore the old database before update and still see this problem.

How can i solve it ??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried resetting the permalink structure to the default, saving it. Then go back in and reselect the permalink structure you previously had. If your previous permalink structure was custom can you provide the sytanx used to create that custom permalink?